# Laravel Class Controller not found because route is weirdly case sensitive

Tags: laravel

I wanted to add a controller to an already existing project of mine. Wrote a controller file, added the link in the admin_api route file and adjusted the view I needed.

On my local machine everything works fine.

On production it failed (it's supposed to retrieve a collection, which is then handled and displayed by a vue js component) and the network monitor showed an error 500.

I ssh into the website and ran `php artisan route:list` which gave me the error

```
In Container.php line 779:

  Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Api\StatsController does not exist
```

Although the file StatsController is in App\Http\Controllers\Admin\API\

After playing around I realized that the problem was with the folder name "API", as laravel was looking for "Api". So apparently it's case sensitive. 
Placing the controller in a new folder "Api" solved the issue.
Moving all the other "API" controllers to "Api" broke their routes. 
when running php artisan route:list and in RouteServiceProvider all routes appear as under Admin/Api.

What I don't get is where is this being registered? Is there a way to change this?
I find it quite annoying that the controllers sit now in separate folders and it seems quite absurd to me. I don't quite get how the original controllers worked if they seem to contradict the other configurations.

Working with Laravel 5.7

I would appreciate any insights!

Thanks

Comment: If you're developing on a case-insensitive platform (Windows) but deploying to a case-sensitive one (virtually anything else) you're going to have a Bad Time™. Don't have two separate folders. Pick one consistent way of capitalizing and standardize on it.

Comment: Check the namespace of the StatsController and make sure it's capitalization is consistent with the others. Can you also the post the route snippet that is causing this issue?

Comment: @ceejayoz ah okay, that explains where the issue originates from. although I find it curious that the original classes all worked although their cases were wrong (the dir was API and the namspace Api)

Comment: @Wolfie Like I said, that'll happen on Windows, because of the case-insensitive file system. It breaks when you deploy up to something that's *not* Windows.

Comment: @ceejayoz I understood. I only meant that most of the classes deployed correctly when originally deployed a few months ago, although on paper they should have also broke. The issue came up only with a new class a few days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Just put all the relevant api controllers in a folder named `Api` or `API` (just pick a convention and stick with it), then make sure that each file's namespace (declared at the top) is correct and reflects the folder structure you have chosen.

For example, if your controllers are in `app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Api`, check that each controller file begins with:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Api;

// Rest of code...
```

Answer (score 0):

`StatsController.php` must have the namespace as `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\API`. In `Controller.php` you have to import as `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\API\StatsController`. After that, run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: great thanks, `composer dump-autoload` is the step I was missing!